# Sphere Collider, not pushing things when size is changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make a little pushback effect in my tests arena, I've got a sphere collider and here is my script:

```
// PushBack Class Script
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
    { 
        explosion_ball.transform.position = transform.position;
        StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint());
    }

    IEnumerator WaitAndPrint()
    {
        float i = 0;
        while (i < 1)
        {
            i += 0.01f;
            explosion_ball.radius = curve.Evaluate(i) * 10;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
        }
    }
    //__________//
```

Sphere collider is set and stuff, but it doesn't push things back like I thought it would.

Thanks!

Edit:
`explosion_ball` is a sphere collider, I'm changing it with the point on the animation curve and * it by 10

Comment: dw about the ienumerator name, i will change it at a later date

Comment: _[Why coroutines are evil](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2022/10/06/implementing-time-based-delays-in-unity-3d/)_.

Comment: BTW you don't need to write a single line of code for physics to happen in Unity.  Simply use rigid bodies via the Editor.

Comment: Do the things you expect to be pushed all have a non-kinematic Rigidbody? Does your sphere have one? I would try and add a `WaitForFixedUpdate` to be sure the change is done within the physics frame

Comment: @derHugo all of my objects have "is kinematic" turned off, the sphere just has a collider.

Comment: @MickyD but what do i do with them in the editor? how to I add force from the editor?

Comment: @Jerry _"but what do i do with them in the editor? how to I add force from the editor?"_ - depending on what you are doing you may not have to.  e.g. if you start a game with a ball suspended in mid air and that ball is attached with a rigid body, then Unity automatically makes the ball fall with gravity and will handle collosions with other physics object making them move as needed.  If you wish to add a force, say to a rocket taking off the launchpad, then you can either add a constant force via the Editor or apply it dynamically via code.

Comment: @MickyD The sphere collider can be changed in the inspector (which is what i think you are referring to when saying "editor", but you can't change it in-game via the inspector. So how would i change the radius through inspector?

Comment: _"but you can't change it `in-game via the inspector`"_ - I never said that.  All editing is done whilst the game is stopped when the editor is in Edit mode.

Comment: i'm trying to make the collider expand while the game is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching through the Unity scripting API, found a method in there called
`Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(explosionForce, explosionPosition, explosionRadius, upwardsModifier, mode)`
In order to get the rigid bodies that are to be affected by the explosion I would need to get them using `Physics.OverlapSphere(position, radius)` this gets all of the objects within the radius variable, then get the component.
Combining these two would also look like:

```
Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);
        foreach (Collider hit in colliders)
        {
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Interactable")
            {
                if (hit.gameObject != hitgameObject)
                {
                    Rigidbody rb = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                    if (rb != null)
                        rb.AddExplosionForce(power, transform.position, radius, upForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
                }
            }
        }
```

If there is any explaining that you would like me to do about my variables mentioned I will reply :)

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:Unity Rigid bodies go to sleep so[Also Change interpolation to continuous if collider changes size too quickly]

A.check if obstacle rigid bodies are Sleeping with `onTriggerEnter` and `Wake Up`

```
void OnTriggerEnter(collider){ if(rb.IsSleeping()){rb.WakeUp();}
```

or

B.Attach this forceWakeUp Script to all Objects you want to be obstacles.

```
using UnityEngine;
```

public class forceWakeUp : MonoBehaviour
{
private Rigidbody rb;

```
void Start()
{
    rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    if(rb.IsSleeping()){rb.WakeUp();}
}
```

}

**Forcibly Keeping Many objects awake *Will* impact performance.So** ,your decision.

1. You need to scale up the collider on the object by radius and all the objects it is supposed to wobble need to have Rigid body component attached to them

2.if you ARE doing above things and its not adding any force you could just add a force on all the overlapping objects using the "OnCollisionEnterTrigger" and AddForceMethod radially away from the Sphere
Obstacle.position - Sphere.position  is the vector Radially away from Sphere I think.

You don't need coroutines for this I think.

Comment: thanks for the answer! The coroutine was to slowly change the sphere colliders size, the animation curve is just a line going up like: / and getting the point of the curve to change the radius.

Comment: Did it work? And I am confused about .radius is there a radius component or something even then you didn't get the component how are you changing the radius

Comment: so, explosion_ball is the sphere collider, I'm sorry I didn't say that. I'm changing the radius of explosion_ball (collider)

Comment: I edited my answer I think its bc the Obstacle's rigidbody is sleeping the culprit if the routine is working well

Comment: Also Tell me if it works

Comment: I've never made it sleep in my script, it would be awake by default, wouldn't it?

Comment: Nope it goes to sleep by default on inactivity for better performance.so wake them up on trigger or perpetually awake by the script I gave in answer

Comment: I looked through the unity scripting API for a little bit and found this method called "AddExplosionForce()" this method adds a force to the rigid body specified. I'll add an answer to what this would look like. :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know your curve and what values that evaluation produces, but you can check your code visually with Window/Analysis/Physics Debugger, or write a gizmo:

```
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = new(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(explosion_ball.transform.position, explosion_ball.radius);
}
```

Or simply just use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce.html